# Where are passphrases stored in test rpc?

Tags: solidity, web3js, testrpc

I am new to ethereum. I am trying to create a smart contract.
I would like to know where exactly account passwords are stored?

Currently i am on testrpc, i would like to know where the accounts/passwords are stored.

Answer (score 3):

They should already be unlocked by default, no password necessary.

That is, if you send a transaction from one of the addresses in `web3.eth.accounts` it should just *work*. If that doesn't happen, chances are something else is the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I am creating a webapp which currently runs on testrpc. I would like to create a login mechanism for future when i switch to testnet/public chain. I would like to know what would be a good approach for that purpose. Do i need to implement my own login using "auth0" or something? or are the passphrases saved to ethereum itself?

Comment: That's kind of a large question, and you'd be better off asking it as a separate question. A good answer would be too large for a comment.

Comment: When using Mist with testrpc, mist asks for password when confirming a transaction.

Comment: @RFVenter indeed. any way around it?

Comment: Anybody figured it out? It asks for a password indeed.

Comment: mist ask you to enter the password to send ETH. And Testrpc or ganache seems like not support.